# How to find all $x$ of function $f(x)$ where $x,f(x)\in\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: functions, roots, integers

To start of with some background info on my problem:
I was/am trying to get all integer zeros the function $f(x,y)=\frac{xy-10x-10y}{10xy}$, so $x$, $y$ and $f(x,y)$ should be integers. So I did $\frac{xy-10x-10y}{10xy}=0\Leftrightarrow y=\frac{10x}{x-10}$.
And so it has become my goal to determine all $x$ for which $g(x)=\frac{10x}{x-10}$ and $x$ are integers because so I can get the $x$ and $y$ coordinates for the zeros of $f(x,y)=\frac{xy-10x-10y}{10xy}$.

But how do I go about finding all integer solutions for $g(x),x\in\mathbb{Z}$? Or maybe there is a generally better way to find all integer zeros of a function with two variables?\

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f(x) = \dfrac{10x}{x - 10}$
Let $x - 10  = k.$   So, $x = 10+k$

Therefore,  $\dfrac{10x}{x-10} = \dfrac{10(k+10)}{k} = 10 + \dfrac{100}{k}$

So $k$ divides $100$ and therefore $k = 1,2,4,5,10,...$
You can find respective values of $x$ since $x = 10 + k$

EDIT: Solutions for $f(x) = \dfrac{10x}{3x-10}$

Let $k = 3x-10$

$\dfrac{10x}{3x-10} = \dfrac{100+10k}{3k}=t$ (Lets say it is equal to t)
$100 = k(3t -10)$

Now basically you can write 100 as a product of 2 factors like

100 = 1 x 100...

Now check for which values you get t as an integer and you will get your answer.

Comment: Thank you a lot! How would I need to define $k$ if my function would be something like this: $f(x)=\frac{10x}{3x-10}$? As $k=3x-10$?

Comment: @RulingPencilRuler Exactly. $k = 3x -10$ basically it is easier if there is no subtraction or addition in the denominator. This is a standard technique

Comment: Sorry for bothering you again. If $k=3x-10$ then that would mean $\frac{10x}{3x-10}=\frac{10}{3}+\frac{100}{3k}$. What now? There shouldn't be any number that can be multiplied by three and is still a divisor of $100$, but there are solutions like $x=20$ and $f(x)=4$

Comment: @RulingPencilRuler I will add the solution to the question you have asked in the edit.

Comment: @RulingPencilRuler Please check now I have edited it. You can ask if you have any doubt.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that, $$f(x)=\frac{10x}{x-10}=\frac{10x-100+100}{x-10}=10+\frac{100}{x-10}$$ So, you should find all $x \in \mathbb Z$ such that $x-10$ divides $100$, which can be done easily considering the factors of $100$.